# Projection on transverse traceless Gauge

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, gravitational-waves, linearized-theory

I am reading [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=AqVpQgAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) book about Gravitational waves.

On page 10 and 11 Maggiore says that

*Given a plane wave solution $h_{\mu\nu}$ propagating in the direction $\hat{n}$, outside the sources, already in Lorentz gauge ($\partial_\nu h^{\mu\nu}$) but not yet in the TT gauge, we can find the form of the wave in the TT gauge as follows:
$$h_{ij}^{TT}=\Lambda_{ij,kl}h_{kl}$$*

where

$$\Lambda_{ij,kl}=\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}-\frac{1}{2}\delta_{ij}\delta{kl}-n_jn_l\delta_{ik}-n_in_k\delta_{jl}+\frac{1}{2}n_kn_l\delta_{ij}+\frac{1}{2}n_in_j\delta_{kl}+\frac{1}{2}n_in_jn_kn_l$$

To prove the statement I think one has to show that $h_{0j}^{TT}=0$ and $h_{jj}^{TT}=0$. I start with the former:

$$h_{0j}^{TT}=\Lambda_{0j,kl}h_{kl}=(\delta_{0k}\delta_{jl}-\frac{1}{2}\delta_{0j}\delta{kl}-n_jn_l\delta_{0k}-n_0n_k\delta_{jl}+\frac{1}{2}n_kn_l\delta_{0j}+\frac{1}{2}n_0n_j\delta_{kl}+\frac{1}{2}n_0n_jn_kn_l)h_{kl}\\=h_{0j}-\frac{1}{2}\delta_{0j}h-n_jn_lh_{0l}-n_0n_kh_{kj}+\frac{1}{2}n_kn_lh_{kl}\delta_{0j}+\frac{1}{2}n_0n_jh+\frac{1}{2}n_0n_jn_kn_lh_{kl}=(*)$$

where I have defined $h=h_{ll}$.

**Now my problem is that I don't see why $(*)$ should be zero?** I can only use the Lorentz Gauge consition:

$$\partial_0 h^{\mu0}+\partial_ih^{\mu i}=0\Rightarrow k_0 h^{\mu0}+k_ih^{\mu i}=0\Rightarrow n_0 h^{\mu0}+n_ih^{\mu i}=0 ~~~~(**)$$

where I have used that $h_{\mu\nu}=e_{\mu\nu}(k)e^{ik_\alpha x^\alpha}$ and $n_i:=k_i/|\vec{k}|, n_0:=k_0/|\vec{k}|$

My hope was that I can set $n_i h^{ij}=0$ in $(*)$ but looking at $(**)$ this seems not to be the case... What am I overlooking?

Comment: The definitional equation uses spatial indices only $i,j,k,l$.  So there is no $h^{TT}_{0j}$ in that definition.  You could extend the definition to include all four spacetime dimensions. But you would need to be careful about raised/lowered indices, and possibly about the use of kronecker $\delta$ and metric $g$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comment. I was just able to show it. It is easy to see that $n_i h_{ij}^{TT}=0$ and $h_{ii}^{TT}=0$. And that was everything to show!